# Why do closed questions appear in top questions?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Why do closed questions appear in top questions?  This just pushes other more worthy questions further down.

[image: A question closed as duplicate is the 4th item in Top Questions. It was modified 16 seconds ago.]

Comment: Probably because they haven't dropped out of the list yet.  Caching ...

Comment: "This just pushes other more worthy questions" - questions which are still open are not immediately more worthy, they're simply not closed yet. Questions which are closed are not automatically less worthy, they're simply not ready to be open yet.

Answer (score 13):

Note that on the right side of that question you marked there is a:

> modified 16 secs ago

Closed questions get bumped to the top of the home page just as regular questions do upon edits. This makes sense when you think about it. True, the question will probably go to the reopen votes review queue, but this way it gets right into the eyes of its proper audiences to evaluate if it's worthy of a reopen following that edit (assuming they bother to look at a closed question...).

If we didn't have that, chances are that closed questions will just stay that way - forever floating in the void, waiting for the Roomba to take them out of their misery (which is probably already too close to true).

Comment: Bumping makes also sense in case of possible abuse, eg. a strangely vague question getting closed and is then edited (and revealed) to be spam.